# Adding together values of jQuery.html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition

How would I add together the values pulled from two separate jQuery.html() calls? Example:

```
<div id="a">27</div>
<div id="b">3</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = $("#a").html();
  var b = $("#b").html();
  var c = a + b;
});
```

All the above does is concatenate var a and b into c (i.e. c = 273) because a & b are strings. How do I get the actual values so that I can properly add them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either

```
var a = +$("#a").html();
```

or

```
var a = parseInt($("#a").html(), 10);
```

both of which cast the string to an integer. For more info, see [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Use the parseInt() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a = parseInt($("#a").html(), 10);
 var b = parseInt($("#b").html(), 10);
 var c = a + b;
});
```

Comment: Make sure to specify the base so that leading 0s don't screw things up.

Comment: Good point thanks - something I've overlooked on more than one occasion - updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+` in both operands

```
var c = +a + +b;
```

Comment: `x- -y` is shorter more [info here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5045/3563)

Comment: imho `+a + +b` is more readable than `x- -y`, but nonetheless good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `text()` instead of `html()`.

```
var x = parseInt( $(el).text(), 10 );
```